# Using repmat() in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I need to generate the trial order of my stimuli for an experiment consisting of 10 experimental blocks:

- There should be 100 trials per block.
- There are 20 images as stimuli.
- Within each block, the 20 stimuli should
  be shown 5 times each.
- The order of the stimuli should be fully randomized.
  (Meaning, NOT 1:20 in random order, then 1:20 in random order, and so on.
  All 100 trials should be randomized across each block!)

I have to make a matrix that represents the trial order of my experiment, in which the rows represent the 10 blocks, and the columns represent the stimuli to
 be shown in order from column 1 - to column 100.

I figured out that I should use the function `repmat()`, but I can't solve this.

Comment: Why do you believe `repmat` should be used?  From your description, I find it highly unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it, just adjust your values for the number of blocks and block size according to your needs. No `repmat` used though.

```
Nblocks = 10;
Nchoices = 20;
Ndisp = 5; 

Ntrials = Ndisp*Nchoices;

array = ceil([Nchoices/Ntrials:Nchoices/Ntrials:Nchoices]);
perms = array(cell2mat(cellfun('randperm',mat2cell(Ntrials*ones(Nblocks,1),ones(Nblocks,1),1),'UniformOutput',0)));
```

It's a good idea to split the longer wrapped command into individual steps if you want to make sense of it in more depth. Look in particular at the documentation for individual functions and particularly [ceil](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ceil.html) and [randperm](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html).

Comment: Cool! That's what I had in mind more or less!

Comment: @rayryeng If you have a different idea you should post it. Your solutions are inspiring and I have to admit I lifted the `ceil` trick from LuisMendo :-) who likes to use it. I think there might be better ways, perhaps even with repmat?

Comment: Without using `repmat`, I would have done it this way.  I'll admit that I got the `ceil` bug from Luis Mendo as well :)  BTW, thanks very much for the sentiment :)  I'll mull it over here and if I have something to contribute, I most certainly will.  Thanks!